# DotNetZip Creates corrupt archives (bad CRC)

Tags: c#, zip, checksum, dotnetzip

There's a strange problem with DotNetZip that I can't seem to find a solution to.
I've searched for a few hours now and I just can't find anything on this, so here goes.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var archive = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile()) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        //                                string     byte[]
        var entry = archive.AddEntry(file.Name, file.Data);
        entry.ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10); // Just for testing
    }
    archive.Save(ms);
}
return ms.GetBuffer();
```

I need to add the modified time, which is rather crucial, but right now I just have a dummy timestamp.

When I open the file with WinRAR, it says "Unexpected end of archive". Each individual file has checksum 00000000, and WinRAR says "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged". I can repair it, which brings it down 20% in size and makes everything OK. But that's not really useful..

When I make a breakpoint after adding all the entries, I can see in `zip.Entries` that all the entries have that same bad CRC, but all the data seems to be there.
So it shouldn't be the way I save the archive that's the problem.

I use my file collection elsewhere without problems, which adds to DotNetZip being weird. Well either that or I misunderstand something :)

Comment: `GetBuffer` is certainly wrong, since the buffer is often bigger than the content. Use `ToArray()`. Or carefully handle the incompletely filled buffer in the consuming code.

Comment: I'm glad we got that out of the way. It actually solved the problem. Can you add that comment as answer so I can accept it as such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetBuffer` is certainly wrong. It returns the internal buffer of the `MemoryStream`, which is often bigger than the actual content.

To return an array that only contains the actual content, use `ToArray()`.

Or you could carefully handle the incompletely filled buffer in the consuming code. This would reduce GC pressure, since you don't need to allocate a whole new array for the return value.

If the zip-archive is large, I'd also consider saving to a file directly, instead of assembling the archive in-memory.

Comment: Thanks, CodeInChaos. You have some good points here. Handeling of the buffer would be to remove all trailing 0 bytes?

Comment: That depends on the calling code. It'll amount to passing around the length of the valid data, and treating it appropriately. You can't consider all trailing `0` bytes invalid, only those beyond `ms.Length`.